# Help identifying this bird from Southern Brazil

Tags: species-identification, ornithology

[image]

I've seen a few of these birds at my university located in the extreme south of Brazil.

I noticed they usually stay on wet areas and like to eat small critters, such as worms and young tadpoles (I'm not completely sure about the last one).

I also noticed they usually stay alone in a particular area or, at maximum, two in the same location.

Also, here we also have many [Southern Lapwings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Southern_lapwing), which are in the breeding season, and one of them sometimes attacks the bird in the picture (for apparently no reason). When attacked by the Lapwing, this bird bristles the feathers of his neck and just dodges the Lapwing's attacks.

Does someone know what bird is this?

P.S.: Sorry for the bad picture. I couldn't get closer to it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is [*Syrigma sibilatrix*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whistling_heron), the whistling heron. In Brazil we call it *"maria-faceira"*.

[image]

Here is *Syrigma sibilatrix* page in Wiki Aves ("aves" is birds in Portuguese): http://www.wikiaves.com.br/maria-faceira

Wiki Aves is by far the best source for birds in Brazil. It is a very well documented and reliable source, maintained by great ornithologists.

PS: Regarding the Southern lapwings: they are not really *attacking*, they are just trying to drive off the intruder. And there is a reason: the lapwings nest on the ground. I was *"attacked"* by them several times (I'm from the Southern Brazil), when I inadvertently approached their nest.

Comment: Maria-Faceira. I laughed hard at this one :P. I'm quite familiar with the behavior of the Lapwings too. I just though a little strange that their offsprings are already quite grown up and the Maria-Faceira isn't too close to them. I guess the Lapwings are just a little short-tempered ^-^ Thanks!

Comment: Yes, the lapwings (or *"quero-quero"*) are very short-tempered!

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik What's the meaning of "faceira"?

Comment: It's something between 'happy' and 'in a good mood'. For example, when a kid receives a christmas gift and stays happy all day long about it, we say that the kid is "faceira" (nor very usual though).

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik do you speak Portuguese? Faceira also means coquettish and flirtatious.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Yes, I'm Brazilian, but I can assure you I have never heard anyone using this word with this meaning.

Comment: They do in the northeast, where it has a more sexual meaning. I lived in Floripa and I never heard this word there.